# HTTP: redirect "/foo" to "/foo/"

Tags: html, http, amazon-cloudfront

I have a web page currently hosted at `https://somesite.zz/foo/`.  When loaded, that returns `https://somesite.zz/foo/index.html`, which loads various CSS and JavaScript using relative paths:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
```

Since the paths are relative, the browser loads `https://somesite.zz/foo/default.css` and `https://somesite.zz/foo/scripts.js` and everyone is happy.  The problem is when someone omits the trailing slash and loads `https://somesite.zz/foo`.  The server still returns the contents of `https://somesite.zz/foo/index.html`, but now the browser doesn't realize that it is in a subdirectory so the relative paths are wrong: it tries to load `https://somesite.zz/default.css` and `https://somesite.zz/scripts.js`.  Those 404, of course, so nothing works.

How can I redirect `/foo` to `/foo/` (or otherwise make them equivalent)?  I can't use JS in `index.html` because of my CSP: any JS needs to be in an external file, which I can't load because the paths are wrong.  So this probably can't be solved using JS.  This site is hosted on AWS Cloudfront + S3; is there a way to configure such a redirect there?

Answer (score 0):

With a little more research, I discovered that request-triggered Cloudfront Functions can return responses, so I created the following function with the "viewer request" trigger:

```
function handler(event) {
    var request = event.request;
    var uri = request.uri;
    
    if (uri.endsWith('/')) {
        request.uri += "index.html";
    } else {
        var leafIdx = uri.lastIndexOf('/');
        if ((-1 != leafIdx) && (!uri.substring(leafIdx+1).includes('.'))) {
            return {
                statusCode: 301,
                statusDescription: "Redirect",
                headers: {
                    "location": { "value": request.uri + "/index.html" } 
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return request;
}
```

The first branch of that function does the typical silent "redirect" to index.html.  In the second, I check if the last path component appears to be a file or directory based on the presence or absence of a '.' in the name; anything without a '.' is interpreted as a directory and a 301 redirect is issued.  Since this this is a real HTTP redirect, the browser knows to change its path, avoiding my relative-path problem.